# SEF a certain link

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef

I was trying to SEF a certain link on my website:
http://blahblah/cards/?se=1&search=Search+(e.g.+chase+freedom)&se_cats[]=1&se_6[]=Bank+Secured

I want to make it to http://blahblah/cards/bank-secured, and users shouldn't see any redirection.

I tried multiple extension like MijoSEF and JoomSEF. Neither works. I only want to SEF this link for now.

Does anybody have a quick and easy solution? I am lost.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add a rewrite rule to your .htaccess before the sef rewrite rules Joomla! uses.

Something like:

```
RewriteRule http://blahblah/cards/bank-secured  http://blahblah/cards/?se=1&search=Search+(e.g.+chase+freedom)&se_cats[]=1&se_6[]=Bank+Secured
```

Rewrites by default work like you want so it is simple enough. Only issue is with syntax. You'd probably have to escape parts of the two links with "\" for it to work. And possibly add some stuff to handle possible variations in links. You should consult either the Apache documentation or some web tutorial for that. I **could** look up the details, but it is really better not to add the rule unless **you** have the basic understanding of it yourself IMHO.